# How to Use document.getElementById to do switch the CSS to "display:none"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use `document.getElementById` to change the CSS property.
I tried using this:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("id");
x.style.display = "none";
```

But this is not working.

Do you have any suggestions as to why this will not work?

**EXTRA INFO:**
There is no error returned, my code just straight up does not work.

I am also using the `<img>` tag in the `document.getElementById`

If that helps.

Comment: You are almost right but use like this`var x = document.getElementById("id").style'` and then use `x.display = 'none'`.

Comment: What worked? It doesn't look like you were using `style.display="hidden"` like the similar question.

Comment: @showdev `x.display = 'none'` worked.

Comment: Any idea why? [Your original method](https://jsfiddle.net/jydvzwmf/) is equivalent and works as well. I suspect something else was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

- The first thing check in out if really have full access to html file (my be not)
- then try to change this "none" to block my be work !
- try this form `document.getElementById("id").style.display = "none";`
- try this form   `document.getElementById("id").style.visibility = "hidden";`

Comment: Thank you! This worked as well, I really appreciate your feedback!